# tf tutorial warning message

Tags: ros, tutorial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf) tutorial, but I got the following messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_listener.py", line 57, in <module>
    (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/turtle2', '/turtle1', rospy.Time())
tf.ExtrapolationException: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1333037934.805088997, but only time 1333037934.805421114 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [/turtle1] to frame [/turtle2]
[turtle_pointer-6] process has died [pid 3789, exit code 1].
log files: /home/user/.ros/log/e0b84f1e-79ba-11e1-87ee-0023aea58509/turtle_pointer-6*.log
```

Could anyone resolve this problem?

My system info: Ubuntu 11.04, ROS electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30784/tf-tutorial-warning-message/) by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have edited turtle_tf_listener.py, and added tf.ExtrapolationException to the list of exceptions caught on line 58, so that my line 58 now reads:

```
except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
```

This basically just catches the exception and moves on. Not sure if this is the recommended solution, but at least I can move on with the tutorial now :)

---

Originally posted by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) with karma: 446 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try rospy.Time(0) instead of rospy.Time()

---

Originally posted by [f_r](https://answers.ros.org/users/2047/f_r/) with karma: 23 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-03-30**:
I am able to replicate this issue though I'm using C++ not python. In my case it occurs even when using ros::Time(0) though it is intermittent.